# Large SVGs not rendering...my fault? browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, svg, chromium

I have a large SVG being created dynamically with code.
An example of a path it makes is;

```
<path id="curveAB" d="M 8307,437 S 8307,447 8451,406 8595,365 8595,375 " stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" fill="none"></path>
```

It used to be that this worked, but I noticed recently (with no code changes) it stopped showing up in the browser.

They stopped working between Chrome 29 and 36 but not sure when.

Its part of a system for drawing arrows between boxs.

You can demo the full thing here;
http://darkflame.co.uk/GreenFruitEngine2/GreenFruitEnginev3.html#fruit

You need to tick "examples/exampleIndex.ntlist", click "Load Index".
Then when its loaded  type in, for example "Fruit" and hit enter.
You should see a lots of boxes - and if it was working there would be lines between them showing the semantic inheritance of properties.

If you use the chrome inspector *you can see the boxes reserving the space each SVG Path should take up*. Its as if the paths arnt visible, but are being calculated.

I notice it also no longer works in Firefox.
Has the SVG standard changed in some way in the last year?
Is there now size limits on SVGs?

This effects a few of my projects and its rather hard to google anything that seems relevant.
The only other possibility I see is I have been formatting SVGs wrongly and it, by co-incidence, used to work fine (and still does) on Chrome 29, but since then Chrome has tightened up its SVG passer and my mistake no longer slips in?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<svg>` has no width or height attributes.  Nor has it been given width or height via CSS.  In that situation, it defaults to 300x150.  So for your page it is hidden up in the top left.  If you specify a width and height it should display properly.

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
```

Chrome recently changed (ie. fixed) its behaviour.  That's why it will have stopped working for you.

Comment: bingo! That did it.
Feel a bit stupid for overlooking that, thanks!